# How can I get the same random array key?

Tags: templating

I am creating a mad libs type of global. My global set is actually called `madLibs`.

Within that set, is a matrix field - that can have unlimited blocks. Each block only has two fields. `actualRole` and `pretendRole`.

What I have is working - but sometimes I might get the `actualRole` from one matrix, and the `pretendRole` from another. Ideally, I'd like to get the same fields from the same random matrix.

```
{# Get all of the matrix blocks for the global set #}
{% set globalSet = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('madLibs') %}

{% if globalSet|length %}

    {# Find out how many matrix blocks exist #}
    {% set madLibsCount = globalSet.madLib|length %} // 2

    {# Generate a random array key. Remember array is zero based #}
    {% set range = range(0, (madLibsCount - 1)) %}

    <h1>{{ globalSet.madLib[random(range)].actualRole }}</h1>
    <p>{{ globalSet.madLib[random(range)].pretendRole }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Sometimes, this is happening:

```
<h1>{{ globalSet.madLib[0].actualRole }}</h1>
<p>{{ globalSet.madLib[1].pretendRole }}</p>
```

I would really like to have this each time:

```
<h1>{{ globalSet.madLib[0].actualRole }}</h1>
<p>{{ globalSet.madLib[0].pretendRole }}</p>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a common reference to the random number you are creating. Otherwise, you are getting a random number twice - and it's just luck that they show up as expected.

Try this:

```
{# Get all of the matrix blocks for the global set #}
{% set globalSet = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('madLibs') %}

{% if globalSet|length %}

    {# Find out how many matrix blocks exist #}
    {% set madLibsCount = globalSet.madLib|length %} // 2

    {# Generate a random array key. Remember array is zero based #}
    {% set range = range(0, (madLibsCount - 1)) %}

    {# Capture a single (random) number #}
    {% set key = random(range) %}

    <h1>{{ globalSet.madLib[key].actualRole }}</h1>
    <p>{{ globalSet.madLib[key].pretendRole }}</p>
{% endif %}
```